# Excel is formatting text in an undesired way (I want no formatting whatsoever)

Tags: excel, formatting, format

excel is turning `8656:2` into `360.668055555556`. I have the formatter set to `Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the cell as Text before you place the value in it, because when you enter `8656:2` Excel is considering it as a time value - which has an equivalent numerical value of `360.668055555556`.

Otherwise, enter the value with a leading apostrophe `'8656:2` to identify it as a text value.

Comment: That is new information, but my advice still holds.

Comment: okay the suggestion to format the cells first, and then paste from the csv  works. thanks.